# Spring/Hibernate not loading ehcache region factory with ehcache jar in dependency tree

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jpa-2.0, ehcache

We have a few maven projects that inherit from eachother.  Our persistence layer project's pom has the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${dep.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I currently have the persistence.xml including:

```
<persistence-unit name="MyModel" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" values="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>

  </properties>
```

In my unit tests for the model project, I am able to get Hibernate to load the ehcache region factory.  However, I go to a child project that inherits this one (leveraging spring to create the entity manager), and it is unable to find the ehcache region factory.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyModel] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:912) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2836) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2832) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:903) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) ~[na:1.6.0_22]
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
... 50 common frames omitted
```

I can see clearly that both ehcache and hibernate are in my maven dependency tree; is there anything special that has to be done in the spring application configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an unrelated misconfiguration issue with side effects.